# Why $f(p)=(1+u^p)^{1/p}$ is always decreasing when $u>0$ and $p>1$?

Tags: calculus

I tried differentiating it and get a whole mess:

$$f'(p)=(u^p+1)^{1/p}\left(\frac{u^p\log{u}}{p(u^p+1)}-\frac{\log{(u^p+1)}}{p^2}\right)$$

And I don't know how to prove that this is always negative when $u>0$ and $p>1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I trust your differentiation.) In the parentheses, it is

$$\frac{u^p\log u^p - (u^p + 1)\log(u^p + 1)}{p(u^p + 1)}.$$

Just look at the numerator.

Comment: That's nice! Put $p$ in the $\log{}$! Thank you.